# POSIX semaphore - how to remove after process closed incorrectly

Tags: c, posix, ipc, shared-memory

So more of a development question.

I create a POSIX semaphore with:

```
sem_init(&mem->rsem, 1, 0);
sem_init(&mem->wsem, 1, 1); // writer gets first turn
```

And I have not done all of my signal handling yet and wanted to know how I can navigate to and remove these semaphores once the process is closed instead of within the process with:

```
sem_unlink (&mem->rsem);
```

I know it is a FD (file descriptor) but am not sure how to find it in the sea of FDs! For instance with POSIX IPC message queue I can do this:

```
cat /dev/mqueue/my_custom_queue
```

and if I want rm that file and it's cleaned up! Again this is mostly for when developing or if I get a deadlock when a process closes and I can not get the semaphore back.

Comment: you seem to be confusing between named and unnamed semaphores

Comment: You are right I was. No need to remove those unnamed semaphores. Just close the shared memory and you are good. Thanks!